# Sums of powers of cosines and sines shifted by $2\pi/3$

Tags: group-theory, geometry, trigonometry, permutations

I have stumbled across these two identities
$$
\begin{split}
\cos^2(x)+\cos^2(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^2(x+4\pi/3) &= 3/2,\\
\cos^4(x)+\cos^4(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^4(x+4\pi/3) &= 9/8.
\end{split}
$$
There is also the more intricate
$$
\begin{split}
\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x+2\pi/3)\sin^2(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^2(x+4\pi/3)\sin^2(x+4\pi/3) &= 3/8,\\
\cos^4(x)\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x+2\pi/3)\sin^4(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^4(x+4\pi/3)\sin^4(x+4\pi/3) &= 9/128,
\end{split}
$$
and of course the most elementary
$$
\cos(x)+\cos(x+2\pi/3)+\cos(x+4\pi/3)=0.
$$

The last identity admits a rather intuitive interpretation in terms of unitary complex numbers centered about the origin. **My questions are**:

1. Do the other identities admit similar more or less intuitive interpretations as well?
2. Do such identities have names?
3. Not all powers and combinations produce a constant; What is the general form of the expressions that do?

**Context**: The first two identities came up while calculating the elastic response of a two-dimensional truss (a planar lattice of nodes connected with springs) that is invariant by rotations of order 3, in which case $x$ describes the orientation of the truss. We know that such trusses must exhibit an isotropic response and that justifies, in a rather convoluted manner, that these expressions must be constants. The other expressions I found by trial and error. I am looking for a satisfying, non-brute-force, non-too-group-theoretic, explanation.

Comment: @ UmbQbify -Key20-: I don't know, but since you mentioned it, there is also $\cos^3(x)+\cos^3(x+2\pi/3)+\cos^3(x+4\pi/3)=3\cos(3x)/4$.

Comment: I have always thought about the first equation in terms of a fact from high school physics. Power is proportional to the square of the voltage so *The sum of the powers of various phases in [three-phase power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power) is constant.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Version of 20.07.20.}}$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Preliminary calculations.}}$

At first,
\begin{cases}
\cos\left(x+\frac{4\pi}3\right) = \cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt]
\sin\left(x+\frac{4\pi}3\right) = \sin\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\tag1
\end{cases}
Denote
\begin{cases}
c= \cos x,\quad s=\sin x,\\[4pt]
\mathcal S_k(f(t),x)=f^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) +f^k(x) +f^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt]
\mathcal Q_k(f(t),x)=f^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)f^k(x) 
+f^k(x)f^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt]
\mspace{93mu}+f^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)f^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt]
\mathcal P_k(f(t),x)=f^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) f^k(x) f^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right).\tag2
\end{cases}
Since
$$\cos\frac{2\pi}3 = -\frac12,\quad \sin\frac{2\pi}3 = \frac{\sqrt3}2,$$
then
$$\cos\left(x\pm\frac{2\pi}3\right) = -\frac c2\mp\frac{s\sqrt3}2,\quad
\sin\left(x\pm\frac{2\pi}3\right) = -\frac s2\pm\frac {c\sqrt3}2.\tag3$$
Applying $(3),$ easily to get

\begin{align}
&\mathcal S_1(\cos t,x) = \cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\cos x +\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\
& = -\frac c2+\frac{s\sqrt3}2\,+c\,-\frac c2-\frac{s\sqrt3}2 = 0,\\[4pt]
&\mathcal Q_1(\cos t,x) = \cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\cos x + \cos x \cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\
&= c\left(-\frac c2+\frac{s\sqrt3}2-\frac c2-\frac{s\sqrt3}2\right)
+\left(-\frac c2-\frac{s\sqrt3}2\right)\left(-\frac c2+\frac{s\sqrt3}2\right)\\
&= -\cos^2 x+\frac14\cos^2x-\frac34\sin^2x = -\frac34,\\[4pt]
&\mathcal P_1(\cos t,x) = \cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\cos x \cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right) = \left(-\frac c2+\frac{s\sqrt3}2\right)\,c\,
\left(-\frac c2-\frac{s\sqrt3}2\right)\\
& = \frac14(\cos^3x-3\cos x\sin^2 x) = \frac14\Re(\cos x + i\sin x)^3 = \frac14\cos 3x.
\end{align}

At the same time,
$$\sin x = \cos\left(x-\frac\pi2\right),\tag4$$
and then
\begin{align}
&\mathcal S_k(\sin t,x) = \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin^k x +\sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right) = \mathcal S_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right) ,\\[4pt]
&\mathcal Q_k(\sin t,x) = \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k x + \sin^k x \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt]
&+\sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)
=\mathcal Q_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right),\\
&\mathcal P_k(\sin t,x) = \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k x \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)
= \mathcal P_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right).\\[4pt]
\end{align}

On the other hand,
\begin{cases}
\cos x \sin x = \frac12\sin(2x)\\[4pt]
\cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) \sin \left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) 
= \frac12\sin\left(2x-\frac{4\pi}3\right)
= \frac12\sin\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\[4pt] 
\cos\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right) \sin \left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right) 
= \frac12\sin\left(2x+\frac{4\pi}3\right)
= \frac12\sin\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}3\right).\tag5
\end{cases}

then
\begin{align}
&\mathcal S_k(\cos t \sin t, x) = \cos^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)+ \cos^k x\, \sin^k x\\
& + \cos^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\ 
&=\frac1{2^k}\left(\sin^k\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)+ \sin^k 2x 
+ \sin^k\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right) = \frac1{2^k}\mathcal S_k(\sin t,2x),\\[4pt]
&\mathcal Q_k(\cos t \sin t,x) = \cos^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) \cos^k x\, \sin^k x\\
& + \cos^k x\, \sin^k x \cos^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\
& + \cos^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\cos^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\
&=\frac1{4^k}\left(\sin^k\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k 2x + \sin^k 2x 
\sin^k\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right.\\
&\left.+ \sin^k\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right)\\
& = \frac1{4^k}\mathcal Q_{k}(\sin t,2x),\\[4pt]
&\mathcal P_{k}(\cos t \sin t,x) = \cos^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) \cos^k x\, \sin^k x\\ &\times\cos^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\, \sin^k\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\\
&=\frac1{8^k}\sin^k\left(2x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^k 2x \sin^k\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}3\right) = \frac1{8^k}\mathcal P_{k}(\sin t, 2x).
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{cases}
\mathcal S_1(\cos t, x)=0\\
\mathcal Q_1(\cos t, x) = -\frac34\\
\mathcal P_1(\cos t, x) = \frac14\cos3x\\
\mathcal S_k(\sin t, x) = \mathcal S_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right)\\[4pt]
\mathcal Q_k(\sin t, x) = \mathcal Q_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right)\\[4pt]
\mathcal P_k(\sin t, x) = \mathcal P_k\left(\cos t,x-\frac\pi2\right)\\[4pt]
\mathcal S_k(\cos t \sin t, x) = \frac1{2^k}\mathcal S_k(\sin t,2x)\\[4pt]
\mathcal Q_k(\cos t \sin t, x) = \frac1{4^k}\mathcal Q_k(\sin t,2x)\\[4pt]
\mathcal P_k(\cos t \sin t, x) = \frac1{8^k}\mathcal P_k(\sin t,2x).\tag6
\end{cases}

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Calculation of sums.}}$

$\mathcal S_1(\cos t, x),\ \mathcal Q_1(\cos t, x),\ \mathcal P_1(\cos t, x)\ $ can be considered as the elementary [symmetric polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricPolynomial.html). In this way,

If $f(t) = \cos t,$ then
$$\begin{align}
&\mathcal S_2 = \mathcal S_1^2 - 2\mathcal Q_1 = \frac32,\\
&\mathcal Q_2 = \mathcal Q_1^2 - 2\mathcal S_1 \mathcal P_1 = \frac9{16},\\
&\mathcal S_4 = \mathcal S_2^2 - 2\mathcal Q_2 = \frac98.
\end{align}\tag7$$
Formulas $(6)-(7)$ allow to fill the table $(8).$

Besides,
$$\begin{align}
&\mathcal P_2(\cos t, x) + \mathcal P_2(\sin t, x)\\ 
&= \cos^2\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\cos^2 x \cos^2\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin^2\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)\sin^2 x \sin^2\left(x+\frac{2\pi}3\right) =\frac1{16}.
\end{align}$$

\begin{vmatrix}
k & f(t) & \mathcal S_k(f(t),x) & \mathcal Q_k(f(t),x) & \mathcal P_k(f(t),x)\\
1 & \cos t       & 0         & -\dfrac34    & \dfrac14\cos 3x\\
1 & \sin t       & 0         & -\dfrac34    & -\dfrac14\sin 3x\\
1 & \cos t\sin t & 0         & -\dfrac3{16} & -\dfrac1{32}\sin 6x\\
2 & \cos t       & \dfrac 32 & \dfrac9{16}  & \dfrac1{16}\cos^2 3x\\
2 & \sin t       & \dfrac 32 & \dfrac9{16}  & \dfrac1{16}\sin^2 3x\\
2 & \cos t\sin t & \dfrac 38 & \dfrac9{256} & \dfrac1{1024}\sin^2 6x\\
4 & \cos t       & \dfrac98  & & \\
4 & \sin t       & \dfrac98  & & \\
4 & \cos t\sin t & \dfrac9{128} & & \tag8
\end{vmatrix}

Any function which depends only from the considered constant polynomials, should be a constant too.

In particular, for the considered functions $f(t)$
$$\mathcal P_k = \mathcal P_1^k,\\
\mathcal S_3 - 3\mathcal P_3 = \mathcal S_1^3 - 3\mathcal S_1\mathcal Q_1 = 0.$$

Comment: looks interesting, but you should better clarify the various steps

Comment: @GCab Thank you for the hint. Renewed. Glad to see you.

Comment: and in fact .. it was interesting ! and now also clear ! I am glad as well to meet you again :)

Comment: @GCab Thank you, once more. Also, for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564232/how-does-the-author-derive-these-relations/3767154#3767154) result.

Comment: @GCab [Interesting integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705505/how-can-i-find-i-n-int-01-frac-x2n-ln-x1-x21x4ndx/3778181#3778181)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, any polynomial identity involving $\cos(mx + c)$ and $\sin(mx+c)$ for various constants $c$ and integers $m$ can be written in the form
$R(z) = 0$ where $z = e^{ix}$ and $R$ is a rational function involving the $e^{ic}$.  For this to be true, the numerator of $R(z)$ must simplify to the polynomial $0$.

For example, let's take
$$ \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x+2\pi/3) + \cos^2(x+4\pi/3)=3/2 $$
Expressed in terms of $z = e^{ix}$, this becomes
$$ \frac{z^2}{4} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4z^2} + \frac{z^2}{4} e^{4\pi i/3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4 z^2} e^{-4\pi i/3} + \frac{z^2}{4} e^{8\pi i/3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4 z^2} e^{-8\pi i/3} = \frac{3}{2} $$
which simplifies to
$$ \left(1 + e^{4\pi i/3} + e^{8\pi i/3}\right) \frac{z^2}{4} + 
\left(1 + e^{-4\pi i/3} + e^{-8\pi i/3}\right) \frac{1}{4 z^2} = 0 $$
and that is true, as we verify by showing $$1 + e^{4\pi i/3} + e^{8\pi i/3} = 0$$
and $$ 1 + e^{-4\pi i/3} + e^{-8\pi i/3} = 0$$
Note that if $w = e^{4\pi i/3}$, the first is $1 + w + w^2 = (1-w^3)/(1-w)$, and
$w^3 = e^{4\pi i} = \left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^2 = 1$.  Similarly for the second.

EDIT: For question 3, you basically want to know what polynomial identities are satisfied by the $e^{ic}$.  If there is only one $c$, then $e^{ic}$ must be an algebraic number, and all polynomial identities it satisfies are multiples of its minimal polynomial.  For example, if $c = 2 m \pi/n$
with $m$ and $n$ coprime, then the minimal polynomial is the cyclotomic polynomial $C_n(w)$.  Things can be more complicated if there are several different $c$.

EDIT: For example, the $6$'th cyclotomic polynomial is $C_6(w) = w^2 - w + 1$, and its roots are $e^{2\pi i k/6}$. where $k$ and $6$ are coprime, i.e. $e^{\pi i/3}$ and $e^{- \pi i/3}$.
We might take $$(z+1/z)(w - 1 + 1/w) = z w + \frac{1}{zw} - z - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{z}{w} + \frac{w}{z}$$
which with $w = \exp(i\pi/3)$ and $z = \exp(ix)$ becomes
$$ 2 \cos(x+\pi/3) - 2 \cos(x) + 2 \cos(x-\pi/3) = 0 $$

Comment: I would be happy to award your answer a second bounty if you can provide the details for the edit: say, given a $c$ such that $e^{ic}$ is algebraic, how can we generate identities such as the ones in the OP?

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to question 3.

Let
$$f_n(x):=\cos^n(x)+\cos^n\bigg(x+\frac{2\pi}{3}\bigg)+\cos^n\bigg(x+\frac{4\pi}3\bigg)$$
$$\small g_n(x):=\cos^n(x)\sin^n(x)+\cos^n\bigg(x+\frac{2\pi}3\bigg)\sin^n\bigg(x+\frac{2\pi}3\bigg)+\cos^n\bigg(x+\frac{4\pi}3\bigg)\sin^n\bigg(x+\frac{4\pi}3\bigg) $$
where $n$ is a positive integer.

This answer proves the following two claims :

**Claim 1** : $f_n(x)$ is a constant function if and only if $n=1,2,4$.

**Claim 2** : $g_n(x)$ is a constant function if and only if $n=1,2,4$.

---

**Claim 1** : $f_n(x)$ is a constant function if and only if $n=1,2,4$

*Proof* :

You already noticed that $f_1(n),f_2(n)$ and $f_4(n)$ are constant functions.

Now, let us prove that if $f_n(x)$ is a constant function, then $n=1,2,4$ as follows :

$$\begin{align}&\text{$f_n(x)$ is a constant function}
\\\\&\implies f_n(0)=f_n\bigg(\frac{\pi}{6}\bigg)
\\\\&\implies 1+\bigg(-\frac 12\bigg)^n+\bigg(-\frac 12\bigg)^n=\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg)^n+\bigg(-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg)^n+0
\\\\&\implies 2^n+2(-1)^n-(\sqrt 3)^n-(-\sqrt 3)^n=0
\\\\&\implies \begin{cases}2^n-2=0&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\\\2(\sqrt 3)^{n-1}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\bigg)^{n-1}-\sqrt 3\bigg)+2=0&\text{if $n$ is even}\end{cases}
\\\\&\implies n=1,2,4\end{align}$$
since for odd $n$ , we have $2^n-2=0\implies n=1$, and for even $n$, letting $h(n):=2(\sqrt 3)^{n-1}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}\bigg)^{n-1}-\sqrt 3\bigg)+2$, we see that $h(2)=h(4)=0$ and that $h(n)$ is increasing for $n\ge 6$ with $h(6)=12$.

---

**Claim 2** : $g_n(x)$ is a constant function if and only if $n=1,2,4$.

*Proof* :

You already noticed that $g_2(n)$ and $g_4(n)$ are constant functions. We have $g_1(n)=0$.

Now, let us prove that if $g_n(x)$ is a constant function, then $n=1,2,4$ as follows :

$$\small\begin{align}&\text{$g_n(x)$ is a constant function}
\\\\&\implies g_n(0)=g_n\bigg(\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg)
\\\\&\implies 0+\bigg(-\frac 12\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg)^n+\bigg(-\frac 12\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}\bigg)^n\\&\qquad\qquad =\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n+\bigg(-\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n+\bigg(\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n\bigg(-\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg)^n
\\\\&\implies 2^n+2(-1)^n-(\sqrt 3)^n-(-\sqrt 3)^n=0
\\\\&\implies n=1,2,4\end{align}$$
where the last step is the same as that of the proof for claim 1.

Answer (score 1):

If $\cos3y=\cos3x$

$3y=2n\pi\pm3x$ where $n$ is any integer

$y=\dfrac{2n\pi}3+x$ where $n=0,1,2$

Again, $\cos3y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y$

So, the roots of $$4\cos^3y-3\cos y-\cos3x=0$$ are  $p=\cos x,q=\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+x\right),r=\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+x\right)$

Using [Vieta's](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) formula, $$p+q+r=\dfrac04\ \ \ \  (1)\text{ and }pq+qr+rp=\dfrac{-3}4\ \ \ \  (2)\text{ and }pqr=\dfrac{\cos3x}4\ \ \ \  (3)$$

By $(1),(2)$  $$p^2+q^2+r^2=(p+q+r)^2-2(pq+qr+rp)=?\  \ \  \ (4)$$

By $(1),(3)$  $$p^3+q^3+r^3=3pqr=?\  \ \  \ (5)$$

**A little Transformation of equation**

- Let $c=\cos^2y$

$$(\cos3x)^2=(4\cos^3y-3\cos y)^2$$

$$\implies16c^3-24c^2+9c-\cos^23x=0$$ whose roots are $p^2,q^2,r^2$

Again applying [Vieta's](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html) formula,  $$p^2+q^2+r^2=\dfrac{24}{16}\  \ \  \ (6)\text{ compare with }(4)$$

$$p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2=\dfrac9{16}\  \ \  \ (7)\text{ and } p^2q^2r^2=\dfrac{\cos^23x}{16}\  \ \  \ (8)\text{ compare with }(3)$$

By $(6),(7)$  $$p^4+q^4+r^4=(p^2+q^2+r^2)^2-2(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)=?\  \ \  \ (9)$$

- Let $s=\dfrac1{\cos y}$

$$\dfrac4{s^3}-\dfrac3s-\cos3x=0\iff(\cos3x)s^3+3s^2-4=0$$ whose roots are $\dfrac1p,\dfrac1q,\dfrac1r$

$$\implies\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q+\dfrac1r=-\dfrac3{\cos3x}=-3\sec3x\ \ \ \ (10)$$

Similarly, $$\dfrac1{pq}+\dfrac1{qr}+\dfrac1{rp}=?\ \ \ \ (11)\text{ and }\dfrac1{pqr}=?\ \ \ \ (12)$$

Finally as  $\dfrac1p=\sec x$ etc.,
using $(10,11),$ $$\sec^2x+\sec^2\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+x\right)+\sec^2\left(\dfrac{4\pi}3+x\right)=\left(\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q+\dfrac1r\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac1{pq}+\dfrac1{qr}+\dfrac1{rp}\right)=?$$

**Generalization**

$$\cos ny=\cos nx$$ Can this be left as an exercise?